# Automated RDS backups and details of their storage in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am responsible for some RDS instances (MariaDB), all running in the same region (with no multi-az setup) and configured to use the automated backup provided by AWS. According to AWS documentation, the automated backups are stored in S3 but there is no detail on the storage class in the documentation.

Business wants assurances that the backups are stored in multiple AZs (not all storage classes offer this!). I've tried to find out more about RDS backup storage through AWS support, but they've been rather unhelpful, claiming these are "internal details" and they can't tell me anything more than I read in the documentation.

So: is it known whether RDS automated backups are stored in multiple AZs, or should I just use AWS Backup with Cross-Region Backups?

Comment: S3 has no user visible AZs. You must trust their service level agreement: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DataDurability.html

Comment: I know S3 has no user visible AZs. But according to the S3 storage class documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html only some storage classes store the objects redudantly across multiple AZs.

Comment: You can always setup bucket replication yourself and have the objects safely stored across 2 regions. Other than this, you're at the mercy of AWS' internal decisions which they won't advertise. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-how-setup.html